# Configuración valores dinámicos con facebook ads y tag manager

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, facebook, facebook-api

Resulta que quiero pasar los valores del checkout de mi woocommerce al evento purchase del pixel de Facebook pero actualmente lo tengo de esta forma

```
<script>fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 0.00, currency: 'USD'});</script>}}
```

Evidentemente son valores por defecto pero lo quiero hacer dinamico quiero que esos valores del checkout pasen a ese evento , esto con el fin de que facebook los capture y me permita mediar estadisticas de retorno como el ROAS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los eventos los estoy manejando desde google tagmanager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería su ayuda en el proceso de implementación de estos valores dinamicos

Answer (score 0):

Desde javascript no se puede recuperar el valor directamente. Se debe hacer desde php, consultando el objeto order. Puedes poner esta función en el fichero functions.php  y usar la acción wp_footer para comprobar si estás en la página de gracias y enviar el pixel de conversión:

```
add_action('wp_footer','trackFacebook');
function trackFacebook()
{
    if (( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) )&&( is_order_received_page() ))
    {
        $order_key= sanitize_text_field($_GET['key']);
        $order= new WC_Order( wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $order_key ) );
        $tracking="fbq('track', 'Purchase', {'value':'".$order->get_total()."','currency':'".$order->get_currency()."'});";
        echo '<script>'.$tracking.'</script>';
    }
}
```

Lo mismo funcionará para TagManager.

También puedes implementar todo el tracking de tu ecommerce mediante el plugin Easy Pixels https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-pixels-by-jevnet/ con la extensión para WooCommerce https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-pixels-ecommerce-extension-by-jevnet/